# Getting EPSG codes from Dotspatial.Projections

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, dotspatial

I have installed Dotspatial.Projections in my Visual Studio C# project.  I have not found a way to get the EPSG codes.

Is there a way to do this using the Dotspatial.Projections library?